OpenLink Virtuoso Retrieve all triple through SPARQL returns type assertion
I'm using OpenLink Virtuoso through the Conductor administration page. I'm making the following SPARQL query in order to retrieve all the triples in a specific graph:
SELECT * WHERE{   
?s ?p ?o.   
}

The problem is that all the retrieved triples are type assertions , namely, all the triples where ?p is rdf:type, while the remaining triples are not retrieved.
With the following SPARQL query:
 SELECT * WHERE{   
 ?s ?p ?o. 
  FILTER (?p != <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>)
 }  

I retrieve all the triples involving the RDF properties (rdf:type excluded) but not all the triples involving the properties defined within the considered graph.
I tried the following query:
 SELECT WHERE
   { ?s ?p ?o  
   FILTER (?p != <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>)
   }

and it retrieves all the triples where ?p can be replaced with one of the properties in the rdf-schema (except rdf:type) but not all the triples where ?p is any property defined in the selected GRAPH.

Where are you limiting the results to a specific graph? I would expect you to use something like SELECT * WHERE { <http://example/mygraph#> { ?s ?p ?o } }. You didn't indicate how many rdf:type triples were returned, so I'm wondering if the result set didn't simply max out based on your INI settings.

the GRAPH keyword is missing, it should be WHERE { GRAPH <http://example/mygraph#> { ?s ?p ?o } }

Regarding the question, did you define the default graph differently? I mean, SELECT * WHERE{    ?s ?p ?o.    } does just query the default graph. You can indeed modified what makes up the default graph with SELECT * FROM <g1_uri> FROM <g2_uri> ... WHERE - or just a particular named graph inside the query pattern as mentioned by @TallTed

I used the "Default IRI Graph" option of Conductor. No matter how I specify the GRAPH, it always retrieves all (and only) the triples with the rdf:type property. I already tried both "FROM" and "GRAPH" keywords.

What versions of Virtuoso and Conductor are you running? Is the SPARQL endpoint publicly accessible, i.e., can you provide a link for us to test directly?

I'm using the version 07.20.3229, build July 27 2021. Unforntunately, I cannot provide access to the dataset.

I strongly advise updating to a current build. Three years brings a lot of fixes and enhancements.

You might be getting partial results from virtuoso. That is a virtuoso feature that can sometimes give confusing results if you don't know it is on.
If you can look at the HTTP headers from the server you could know for sure.
https://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/anytimequeries/

Is there any way I can set the timeout through the web interface?

@Discipulos — The Conductor (browser-based admin interface) allows the dba user to set a number of option values thta are generally managed through the INI file. However, some of these settings (including those for AnyTimeQuery) do not take effect until the instance is restarted — which cannot be triggered through the Conductor.

thank you, I have no control on server side, but this appears to be the main issue!
